# MySQL COUNT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to collect the number of distinct visits in my cp yesterday, then count them.

```sql
SELECT
    DISTINCT `user_id` as user,
    `site_id` as site,
    `ts` as time
FROM
    `cp_visits`
WHERE
    ts >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

For some reason this is pulling multiple results with the same site id....how do i only pull and count the distinct site_id cp logins?

Answer (score 315, accepted):

```
 Select
     Count(Distinct user_id) As countUsers
   , Count(site_id) As countVisits
   , site_id As site
 From cp_visits
 Where ts >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
 Group By site_id
```

Comment: I love SQL because you get questions like "How do I count distinct user IDs" and the answer is just "`Count(Distinct user_id)`"

Comment: for mysql it could return an error because user_id isn't in group by clause

Comment: @AlexeySh. , no it will not give any error.

Answer (score 26):

Overall

```
SELECT
       COUNT(DISTINCT `site_id`) as distinct_sites
  FROM `cp_visits`
 WHERE ts >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Or per site

```
  SELECT
         `site_id` as site,
         COUNT(DISTINCT `user_id`) as distinct_users_per_site
    FROM `cp_visits`
   WHERE ts >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY `site_id`
```

Having the `time` column in the result doesn't make sense - since you are aggregating the rows, showing one particular `time` is irrelevant, unless it is the `min` or `max` you are after.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use a group by clause.

```
SELECT  site_id, MAX(ts) as TIME, count(*) group by site_id
```