# Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, count

im geting this error when trying to do 2 counts inside of my query

first ill show you the query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select c.id, c.number, d.name, 
                    (select count(*) from `parts` where `id_container`=c.id group by `id_car`) as packcount,
                    (select count(*) from `parts` where `id_container`=c.id) as partcount
                    from `containers` as c
                    left join `destinations` as d on (d.id = c.id_destination)
                    order by c.number asc") or die(mysql_error());
```

now the `parts` table has 2 fields that i need to use in the count:
`id_car`
`id_container`

`id_car` = the ID of the car the part is for
`id_container` = the ID of the container the part is in

for `packcount` all i want is a count of the total cars per container
for `partcount` all i want it a count of the total parts per container

Comment: You have a group by in your packcount line and you're trying to return that as a single column value.

Comment: If you really want help with this, I suggest editing your question to include examples of table definitions and data as well as the desired output for your query.  Thank you.

Comment: as StudyOfCrying said, can you please put table structure, inserts and what you want out of your query? It will go much faster that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of GROUP BY You're using

Try something like

```
(select count(distinct id_car) from `parts` where `id_container`=c.id)
```

in You're subquery (can't check right now)

EDIT

PFY - I think UNIQUE is for indexes

Comment: Yea, I was in the middle of indexing a table when I wrote that and confused myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Your grouping in your first sub-query is causing multiple rows to be returned, you will probably need to run separate queries to get the results you are looking for.

Comment: Have you tried select UNIQUE count(id_car) in your first sub query? -edit- Xander beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

This subquery may return more than one row.

```
(select count(*) from `parts` where `id_container`=c.id group by `id_car`) as packcount, ...
```

so, i'd suggest to try something of the following:

```
(select count(DISTINCT `id_car`) from `parts` where `id_container`=c.id) as packcount, ...
```

see: [COUNT(DISTINCT) on dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)

and: [QA on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737628/mysql-count-distinct)