# Count and sum from table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table below that I need to get the number of student that get A in their exam. This is what I want to achieve from table below:

3 A's = 0 student. 2 A's = 3 student.

```
+--------------+------------+------+
|  student_ID  | kod_subjek | gred |
+--------------+------------+------+
| 746123096687 | 02         | A    |
| 746123096687 | 12         | B    |
| 746123096687 | 21         | A    |
| 860206145454 | 12         | A    |
| 860206145454 | 02         | A    |
| 881012085535 | 02         | A    |
| 881012085535 | 21         | A    |
+--------------+------------+------+
```

I try with:

```
mysql> SELECT student_ID, COUNT(gred) FROM data_exam GROUP BY student_ID;
```

The output is:

```
+--------------+-------------+
| student_ID   | COUNT(gred) |
+--------------+-------------+
| 746123096687 |           3 |
| 860206145454 |           2 |
| 881012085535 |           2 |
+--------------+-------------+
```

It not work. It will just count all the grade for specific student. Please help me solve this. Thank you.

Comment: This question already covers this I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737628/mysql-count-distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a_count, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS a_count
  FROM data_exam
  WHERE gred = 'A'
  GROUP BY student_id
) x
GROUP BY a_count
ORDER BY a_count
```

[Example on SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28de8/2) returns:

```
a_count   cnt
      2     3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT num_as, COUNT(1) AS num_students
FROM (
  SELECT student_ID, COUNT(gred) AS num_as
  FROM data_exam
  WHERE gred = 'A'
  GROUP BY student_ID
) counts_by_student
GROUP BY num_as
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but what does it mean by `COUNT(1)`? What does 1 in the count mean?

Comment: `COUNT(1)` will count the number of rows in each group.  `COUNT(expression)` counts the number of times the expression is not `NULL`, and the expression is evaluated for each row.  So `COUNT(student_ID)` would give you the same thing, assuming that `student_ID` is never `NULL`.  In this case we just want the number of rows, so any non-NULL expression will do.  `COUNT(25)` will do exactly the same thing.