# Summing counts in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

We have the following query, performing as expected to, producing a single-column result with integers.

```
select count(ColumnA) - count(ColumnB)
from MyTable
where Occasion > convert(datetime2, concat(convert(varchar(7), Occasion, 126), ‘-01’))
group by convert(varchar(7), Occasion, 126)
```

Now, we'd like to get the aggregated sum of the values. When we tried `sum(...)`, we got the error that aggregating isn't possible.

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

We tried summing directly like so:

```
select sum(count(ColumnA) - count(ColumnB)) ...
```

and tried summing over a whole select ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769474/count-and-sum-from-table)):

```
select sum( select count(ColumnA) - count(ColumnB) ...)
```

getting "error near )", which was even more confusing.

How should we reason to get it under control?

I've found [an answer relying on partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62270686/1525840) but it seems way overhead for such a simple operation as ours. Is that a recommended approach?

Comment: You may use a subqery in `from` clause

Comment: Use a derived table or Common Table Express (CTE) to do your first aggregation (the `COUNT`s in this case) and then `SUM` that in the outer query.

Comment: I believe it's complaining about the CONVERT within the GROUP BY; so do that conversion within a CTE or subquery, then group by the derived column

Comment: The reason is that function takes an [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) as input, but a subquery (even scalar) is not an expression unless it is enclosed by parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you're looking for:

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(ColumnA) AS cntA, COUNT(ColumnB) AS cntB
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Occasion > convert(datetime2, concat(convert(varchar(7), Occasion, 126), ‘-01’))
    GROUP BY convert(varchar(7), Occasion, 126)
    
)
SELECT SUM(cntA - cntB)
FROM cte
```