# Using COUNT & Distinct in PHP pagination

Tags: php

HI I have a PHP Pagination system, what i am trying to do is use Distinct to return only unique values, what happens is the page shows how many pages there should be but doesn't give me any results.

My code is here

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT ip_address, 
                 COUNT(*) as num 
          FROM $tableName  
          WHERE hostname 
          LIKE 'mail%' AND type='6'";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

$stages = 3;
$page = mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']);

if($page){
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
}else{
    $start = 0; 
}   

// Get page data
$query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT ip_address, 
                  hostname 
            FROM masterip_details  
                WHERE hostname 
            LIKE 'mail%' AND type='6' 
                LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($query1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have an index on the `ip_address` field, I'd just use `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) as num`. If you *have* an index, you could just as well do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(type) AS num FROM tbl WHERE hostname LIKE 'mail%' and type = 6 GROUP BY ip_address;
```

Because, if you're grouping on an index, `DISTINCT` is equivalent to `GROUP BY`. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737628/mysql-count-distinct).

The real reason for my answering this question though: *Please*, [don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` extension](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). Use either one of the replacements, [`mysqli_*`, with `i` for improved](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), or [PDO, which seems to be more commonly used](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Thanks i will check out the alternatives, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `DISTINCT` inside the `COUNT` function to count the number of unique IP adresses in your `$tableName` table. Like this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip_address) as num 
             FROM $tableName  
             WHERE hostname 
             LIKE 'mail%' AND type='6'
         ";
```