# How to pick distinct row value based on column in sql/plsql

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider this table:

```
name  mark1 mark2 mark3
x      1      2    2
y      2      2    2
z      1      2    3
```

Here, I need to select the non distinct for example consider row three,  where it contains only one "2" in column2. For this how to write a SQL code? I have made it of using the count and distinct commands but not able to get it.

Comment: describe what you actualy want

Comment: yeah make it more clear...

Comment: count(distinct) is valid expression, do refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737628/mysql-count-distinct

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE mark1 <> mark2 
   AND mark1 <> mark3 
   AND mark2 <> mark3;
```

Output:

```
| NAME | MARK1 | MARK2 | MARK3 |
|------|-------|-------|-------|
|    z |     1 |     2 |     3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b6004/1)** demo

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

in case you need to select all columns contain values that are unequal

like in this case row3

```
SELECT * 
FROM table a 
WHERE a.m1<>a.m2 
  AND a.m2<>a.m3 
  AND a.m1<>a.m3
```

### <kbd>[see fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0659d/2)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question enough, it would be like this:

select * from mark where (mark1<>mark2 and mark1<>mark3 and mark2<>mark3);