# ORDER BY COUNT() without subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery

I have a simple permission system with 3 tables: `users`, `permissions` and `permission_user`. I would like to get all granted permissions with information who it has been granted to. The results should be ordered by:

1. The number of permissions for user (his power), strongest first
2. The date user has been created, oldest first
3. The weight of permission (`weight` column), smallest first

Here's my query:

```
  SELECT `users`.`email`,
         `permissions`.`key`
    FROM `users`
    JOIN `permission_user` ON `permission_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
    JOIN `permissions` ON `permissions`.`id` = `permission_user`.`permission_id`
ORDER BY (
             SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM `permission_user`
             WHERE `user_id` = `users`.`id`
         ) DESC,
         `users`.`created_at` ASC,
         `permissions`.`weight` ASC;
```

It works fine, but I'm wondering if there is any way to do it without a subquery or counting total permissions granted. It's something that is present in the results set, I could just count unique user ID from that, but is that possible?

Comment: Count(Distinct user_id) might be what you are looking for - this looks similar to what you are doing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737628/mysql-count-distinct

Comment: @Giles I tried to group by `permission_user.id` (this is the only column I can group by, because I need all records) and to count `permission_user.user_id`, but I'm getting 1 in all records.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it without subquery.

You can add column `cnt_permissions` to `users` table and recalculate it after create or update user permissions. So, you can use it to order in query.

But if you not like that. This SQL query work faster, because it do subquery only once.

```
SELECT u.`email`,
       p.`key`
FROM (SELECT COUNT(`permission_user`.`permission_id`) as cnt, `user_id` 
      FROM `permission_user`
      GROUP BY `user_id`) as pucnt
LEFT JOIN `users` as u on u.`id` = pucnt.`user_id`
JOIN `permission_user` as pu on pu.`user_id` = u.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `permissions` as p on p.`id` = pu.`permission_id`
ORDER BY 
      pucnt.cnt DESC,
      u.`created_at` ASC,
      p.`weight` ASC;
```

Comment: Is there no way to avoid subquery at all?

Comment: Try this. (I do not check this query, but look in idea anyway)
    SELECT u.`email`,
                  p.`key`,
                  COUNT(pu1.`permission_id`) as cnt_permisions
    FROM `permission_user` as pu
    JOIN `permission_user` as pu1 on pu1.`user_id` = pu.`user_id`
    LEFT JOIN `users` as u on u.`id` = pu.`user_id`
    JOIN `permission_user` as pu on pu.`user_id` = u.`user_id`
    LEFT JOIN `permissions` as p on p.`id` = pu.`permission_id`
    GROUP BY pu1.`user_id`
    ORDER BY 
          cnt_permisions DESC,
          u.`created_at` ASC,
          p.`weight` ASC;