# 3 table query with count

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlplus

I'm having huge difficulty with a 3 table query.

The scenario is that `TEAM` has many or no `MEMBERS`, a `MEMBER` could have many or no `TASKS`. What I want to get is the number of `TASKS` for every `TEAM`. `TEAM` has its own `ID`, `MEMBER` holds this as a FK on `TEAM_ID`, `TASK` has `MEMBER_ID` on the `TASK`.

I want to get a report of TEAM.NAME, COUNT(Person/Team), Count(Tasks/Team)

I have myself so confused, My thinking was to use an Outer Join on TEAM and MEMBER so I have all the teams with any members they have. From here I'm getting totally confused. If anyone can just point me in the right direction so I have something to work from I'd be so greateful

Comment: If you provide samples of tables and expected result table that would hel a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `count distinct`:

[MySQL COUNT DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737628/mysql-count-distinct)

```
select t.name as Team,
    count(distinct m.ID) as Member_cnt,
    count(distinct t.ID) as Task_cnt
from team t
   left join member m
       on t.ID= m.TEAM_ID
   left join tasks t
     on t.MEMBER_ID= m.ID
group by t.name;
```

Comment: Thanks! I had got as far as the left joins previously, I was missing the group by and count distinct instead of the plain count!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with aggregation -- and `count(distinct)`:

```
select t.name,
       count(distinct m.memberid) as nummembers,
       count(distinct tk.taskid) as numtasks
from team t left join
     member m
     on t.teamid = j.teamid left join
     tasks tk
     on tk.memberid = m.memberid
group by t.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

```
SELECT Team.name, COUNT(Person.id_person), COUNT(Tasks.id_task)
FROM Team t,
LEFT JOIN Person p on p.team_id = t.id_team
LEFT JOIN Tasks ts on ts.person_id = p.id_person
GROUP BY p.team_id, ts.person_id
```