# SQL: Count distinct row values in table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I have a similar table to this in SQL:

```
id |tag | entryID
---+----+--------
1  |foo | 0
2  |foo | 0
3  |bar | 3
5  |bar | 3
6  |foo | 3
7  |foo | 3
```

I want to run a query to count distinct rows in the table (with the `id` column dropped). The result should look like this (or a transpose of this table):

```
(tag=foo, entryID=0) | (tag=foo, entryID=3) | (tag=bar, entryID=3)
---------------------+----------------------+---------------------
2                    | 2                    | 2
```

What should this query look like?

**Note**: The values in each of the columns are not known beforehand.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all that you can show us to get us started, or are you asking for a quotation for the work

Comment: Dou know the values for tag and entry beforehand?  If so, you can use `conditional aggregation`.  If not, you'll need to combine that approach with `dynamic sql`.

Comment: Similar to:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737628/mysql-count-distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(tag = 'foo' and entryId = 0) as "tag=foo, entryID=0",
       sum(tag = 'foo' and entryId = 3) as "tag=foo, entryID=3",
       sum(tag = 'bar' and entryId = 3) as "tag=bar, entryID=0"
from t;
```

However, the normal method is to put the counts in rows, not columns:

```
select tag, entryId, count(*)
from t
group by tag, entryId;
```

The rows are much more versatile, because you don't have to list out every combination you might want to match.